# How to align form fields within a table for inline editing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, spring

I am developing a webapp using Spring, jsp, javascript, jquery.

I display a table using datatables.
When I click on a table row I want it to change all fields to an inline edit inputs, selects etc. In addition I want to show some extra input fields in the next row and a save button.

Now I see several ways of doing this. I am not sure which one to take.

1. I can get a handle to selected row and then iterate over the td and transform them to input/select fields. I can then insert an extra row for the new fields and the save button.
   I don't see this as a clean solution. I will have to issue a Post manually instead of using the Spring ModelAttribute binding for the form. (Can I still use ModelAttribute here?)
2. I can create an edit form in a jsp file which looks like:

   `<form:form action="" commandName="">
   <td> <input ... > </td>
   <td> <select ... > </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td> <label> <input new field> </td>
   <td> <button> </td>
   </tr>`

Note I do not have a beginning  in a jsp file as I plan to reuse the tr from the existing row in the table.
This way I would be able to have a clean form and also use the update method I have already written which binds the form to a Java class. Also I do not have to bother about the alignment of input fields with the column names.

The generated html looks like
    
      
      
      
      
    
    ...

The problem with this approach is the placement of form element in the html causes the entire form to be cramped into one cell of the table which does not look good and messes up the whole layout. Is there a way out? Should I just replace the contents of the table with a  having a colspan and then put divs inside this  element and fine tune the css to ensure that the input fields align with the column names in the table?

[image: Image showing the bad alignment]

Is there a better solution you can suggest?
In case the question is not very clear I can fill in more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I would do (coming from a server-side development background, as I know developers love easy solutions)

1. Wrap the table with a single form
2. on Edit row (clicking row) open an ajax request that returns pure html that looks like the exact tr, only with whatever extra you want to include:

---

```
<tr><td><input type="text" name="text1" ... /></td><td>second row... </td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">And hey, here is more, and the save button ... </td></tr>
```

---

1. in jQuery replace tr with content retrieved `(myTr.replace($(ajaxResponse)))` or something similar
2. now Save button is a regular submit for the form
3. if you want to submit via ajax, once done, return the old html in your ajax response and replace the two trs with the old tr (you just need to hook it by giving new trs an attribute that you can find easily in jquery)
4. don't forget to switch off a global key to prevent double editing, users can edit one row at a time

---

**Update: adding a second solution to dump load on client instead of server**

To avoid overloading the server (though I wouldn't be worried about it until it becomes a regular habit), you can make your form fields as a template inside your HTML and use string replacement (or jQuery Templates), so instead of ajaxing to get response in step 2, you call the template, and replace the strings with attributes you save in every row... like this:

```
<div id="myTemplate"> // or you can use jQuery script templates
    <tr><td><input type="text" name="${Name}" ... /> id is ${Id}</td><td>${SecondRow}... </td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2">Save button here.... and may be more text ${MoreText}</td></tr>  
</div>
```

in every row in your code add sufficient attributes or ids to know what you want to replace with, like this:

```
<tr data-itemid="34"><td ><input type="text" name="text1" id="findme" ... /></td><td data-moretext="here is more text">second column </td></tr>...etc
```

so now in your replacement script:

```
$("#myTemplate").html().replace("${Name}", $(thisrow).find("#findme").attr("name"))
    .replace("${Id}",$(thisrow).attr("data-itemid"));
```

etc...

Of course after submission it has to be a to server, but in case user "cancels" you can have another readonly template

By the way, that is the way I usually go with, I use jQuery templates, and create edit and view templates, but I also repeat edit forms and I use jQuery ajax submit manually... but that... my friend, is not a simple clean and maintainable solution I'm afraid

Comment: that sounds somewhat cool ... since I will not be having hidden input elements in every row.

Comment: Don't you think its a costly solution. For each editing you are making a server trip. Then if user don't want to edit. You make again a serve trip to replace the TR.

Comment: it is an easy maintainable solution that would start creating an overhead at a large threshold (like if we expect users to edit EVERY row)... the next solution would be jQuery templates (or what I call HTML islands)... updating the answer to include that other way...

Comment: @ZahidRiaz I will probably do it using an edit button after selecting the row.

Answer (score 1):

I've been into an issue like this a year before. This is a messy problem. Either way if you traverse each td of row and convert it into text field or You can create a separate jsp file for this.

But the best in this case is to change the content of td to input field and post the data manually. because in this case you cannot wrap form tag around tr. You have to manually post the values of each input field.

P.S The very best solution is to create an edit dialog.

Comment: Thanks Zahid ... I am surprised that I found someone who has been through a similar problem before. Were you in the exact situation - using datatables, spring, jsp?
What do you think about the "hack" of aligning divs containing input elements with the columns of the table - I haven't given it a try as I am new to CSS but eventually it seems like a hack that might work.

Comment: Yeah its the same. Spring, JSP, Hibernate etc. If you go for the divs then I guess it would be difficult to use datatable. as far as I know datatables have inline edit facity through some plugin. Check that out if that may help you

Answer (score 1):

There is another solution, but I'm under the impression you won't like it very much... you can use a single form for the whole datatable (wrapping the whole table in a form is permitted) generate input fields for the current row and if it's updated submit the form asyncronously with javascript and restore td contents to the original html, if you name your fields such as name="field[]" you can also submit multiple rows at a time (I don't know if you'd want that though).

You can write html code such as

```
<form action="">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="row[]" value="1"/><input name="field[]"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>field value for row2</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="row[]" value="3"/><input name="field[]"/></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

you can just grab the form with jquery and submit it via xmlhttprequest as I suspect you would if each row was a separate form (which is illegal), if you don't want multiple rows, just remove the [] and submit each row
and upon submitting the values you get them numbered correctly, don't know exactly how it would behave in java but in php I'd get the following:

```
$_GET[row][0] = 1;
$_GET[field][0] = 'value typed in row1';
$_GET[row][1] = 3;
$_GET[field][1] = 'value typed in row3';
```

Alternative table definition to avoid having the same name again

```
<form action="">
<table>
<tr><td><input name="field[1]"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>field value for row2</td></tr>
<tr><td><input name="field[3]"/></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

It's the same table as above only you set explicit indexes for each entry thus avoiding duplicate names in the response, preferrably use a unique identifier which can describe the row from the table that you're modifying in there (when possible I use the primary key) instead of the row number, just in case that wasn't clear enough.

Comment: I don't want to update multiple fields at a time. Are you suggesting that I copy over the respective values of the input/select field to the common form's input/select fields and then submit the form?
May not be very clean but I guess it may work ... but working on the web we have to use workarounds I guess

Comment: You don't have to copy anything anywhere, if you wrap the table in a form the fields will already be at their correct places so you can just submit the common form since there's only one and it already contains all the fields. Will type some clarification into the answer.

Comment: @iamrohitbanga updated answer, hope what I was saying is more clear now, made a very simplified table design for easier understanding, you should use the affected data's primary key as a value for row[]

Comment: sounds good i will give it a try not sure if spring would allow me to have multiple inputs with same commandName but worth a try

Comment: OK I haven't got time to test it out till now ... but will update you once I do. But one question here - how will the form bind to the fields in the right row. It won't know which ones to use ... There are multiple fields within the form with the same name. Not sure which ones will be picked up by the form or if that is even allowed.
Also the size of table will approximately double - but I guess we will have to deal with that, not a big problem for now.

Comment: Array naming in html is legal, plus you don't have to name all your fields the same, if you're worried about that, adding a second revision to the answer, for a easier to understand syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

1. Wrap whole table in the form
2. have the data entries as disabled inputs with their borders hidden via CSS
3. when user clicks edit, enable the inputs and show the borders
4. You'll probably need hidden  elements for each field
5. When user submits the form, post via ajax and set the inputs back to disabled with hidden borders

Answer (score 1):

What about `contenteditable`?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/XQekC/

jQuery:

```
var ctrlDown = false;
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which = "ctrlKey") {
        ctrlDown = true;
    }
}).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which = "ctrlKey") {
        ctrlDown = false;
    }
});


$('#example').dataTable();

$("#example tr").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("row_selected") && ctrlDown) {
        submitRow($(this));
        return false; // Break out so the next if doesn't run
    }
    else if ($(this).hasClass("row_selected") && ctrlDown == false) {
        return false; // Break out so the next if doesn't run
    }

    if ($(this).siblings(".row_selected").length && ctrlDown == false) {
        $(this).siblings(".row_selected").each(function() {
            submitRow($(this));
        });
    }

    $(this).addClass("row_selected");
    $(this).children("td").each(function() {
        $(this).attr("contenteditable", true);
    });
});

function submitRow(elm) {
    var data = [];
    $(elm).removeClass("row_selected").children("td").each(function() {
        data.push($(this).text());
    });
    alert(data); // This will stop the keyup from firing, but you won't (I hope) really be using alerts
}​
```

This has everything but a submit-to-server function, it's also completely inline and has support for selecting multiple rows.

The only bug is, when it shows the data alert the focus goes off of the main window so the keyup event never fires, since you probably won't be using alerts this shouldn't be an issue. To fix it in the fiddle, press and release ctrl after the alert closes before clicking a row.

Comment: contenteditable sounds interesting but i would definitely prefer something that allows me to reuse some of the server side code.

Comment: that handles the post using spring modelattribute linked to a form object. also I will have selectors in some of the fields.

Answer (score 0):

I see couple of problems

1. Your no. Of columns in the table & the edit columns you show are different
2. You might not be having complete data to edit the row so you might need to do an Ajax call and get it

If you have complete data on then you don't need point 2, let's assume you have a function f called with the clicked tr as the parameter

```
function f(row)
{
     var newRow = yourTable.insertRow(parseInt(row.rowIndex,10)+1);
     //you can place the above or below the clicked row , or you can even make the row visible false And then show the new row
     Var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
     newCell.colspan = 6;//the count if columns in your table row
     NewCell.innerHTML = " put your HTML content here";
}
```

Comment: Agreed, I can do this but wanted a neat way to do it with Spring.
I have incomplete data so I am doing a ajax call as you rightly pointed out.